# Disabling Xdebug's dumping of caught exceptions

Tags: php, exception, debugging, xdebug

By default Xdebug will dump any exception regardless of whether it is caught or not:

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
}
echo 'life goes on';
```

With XDebug enabled and the default settings this piece of code will actually output something like the following (nicely formatted):

```
( ! ) Exception: in /test.php on line 3 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0003  52596   {main}( )   ../test.php:0
life goes on
```

Is it possible to disable this behaviour and have it dumping only the uncaught exceptions?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: I'm about to conclude that this is a bug, since xdebug.show_exception_trace is disabled by default yet it doesn't behave as expected (using Xdebug v2.0.5 with PHP 5.2.10 on Ubuntu 9.10).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the [xdebug.show_exception_trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) option (note it's not enabled by default).

> xdebug.show_exception_trace
>
> Type: integer, Default value: 0
>
> When this setting is set to 1, Xdebug will show a stack trace whenever an exception is raised - even if this exception is actually caught.

Comment: I agree this has something to do with xdebug.show_exception_trace. I think that when set to 0 it should ignore caught exceptions, but somehow this doesn't work even when disabling it explicitly.

Comment: Talk to Derick on #php.pecl @ EFNet or use the bug tracker at http://bugs.xdebug.org/

Comment: This last comment makes your answer complete :) I'm definitely going to report this bug in case I can still reproduce it in 2.1.0RCx. Thanks.

Comment: having the same problem here. Did you report the bug?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is namespaced, the catch block should reference `\Exception` -- *with the backslash* -- if there's no backslash then PHP will look for `Exception` in your current namespace. This usually fails and the uncaught exception is passed to Xdebug.

The following code passes the exception to Xdebug:

```
namespace foo;

try {
    new \PDO(0);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught!";
}
// Fatal error: Uncaught exception...
```

Adding a backslash before Exception will look for (and find) `Exception` in the global namespace:

```
namespace foo;

try {
    new \PDO(0);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught!";
}
// Exception caught correctly
```

Manually throwing exceptions can be confusing (which is why I used PDO above). If we try to throw an Exception from the current namespace, PHP tells us Exception doesn't exist there:

```
namespace foo;

try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught!";
}
// Fatal error: Class 'foo\Exception' not found
```

Throwing a global exception without a global reference in the catch block fails differently:

```
namespace foo;

try {
    throw new \Exception();  // global Exception
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught!";
}
// Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in...
```

In light of all this, it's probably a good idea to always prefix the catch's `Exception` with a backslash.

```
namespace foo;

try {
    throw new \Exception();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught!";
}
// Exception caught correctly
```